# How to change stack size limit in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, stack-overflow, stack-size

In my library (Scheme in JavaScript) I have a test that should fail because it calculates
(! 1000) and it should pass when TCO (tail call optimization) is implemented. But recently NodeJS probably increased the stack size limit because the test passes which means it failed to fail.

Is there a way to make stack size smaller in NodeJS? So I don't need to increase the value of the factorial function to overflow the stack.

**EDIT**: note that `--stack-size` option discussed on [GitHub](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/32221) may crash node. I would like to have a stack overflow error but for a smaller value than 1000.

Comment: @CherryDT I will need to keep increasing the value when Node will decide that the computers have more power and have more ram. Also the result of !1000 is quite big I would like to not have to change that number at all (I use BigInt). The tests should be independent of the environment they run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `--stack-size` V8 option (see also [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/6360)).

To see the default size, you can check `--v8-options`:

```
$ node --v8-options | grep -B0 -A1 stack-size
  --stack-size (default size of stack region v8 is allowed to use (in kBytes))
        type: int  default: 984
```

(I don't know of any way to read the default or current value programmatically other than invoking and parsing `node --v8-options`.)

You can then specify a new stack size with that option:

```
$ node --stack-size=512 index.js
```

You can also set this from the program itself using [`v8.setFlagsFromString`](https://nodejs.org/api/v8.html#v8setflagsfromstringflags):

```js
const v8 = require('v8');
v8.setFlagsFromString('--stack-size=512');
```

Note that the available V8 options may change in the future in newer versions of V8 used in node.js. (For example I believe this option was called `stack_size` with an underscore before, but now it's `stack-size` with a dash.) You could use the [`v8flags` package](https://github.com/gulpjs/v8flags) package or programmatically invoke `node --v8-options` to raise an error if the option no longer exists so you can adjust the test.